# How to get values from a Datagridview Combobox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

- I have the DataGridview named "DataGridView1".
- In the DataGridView there are two columns one named "Process" and
  another named "Size".
- The Size column is a ComboBox.
- When I click a button to create a process, it has to insert "1" in
  the Process column and Get the size the User typed, and put on the
  "Chart1" (a bar graphic type).
  -I want to get the Size and store in a variable called "UsedMemory" and put on the chart.

  ```
  Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("1") 'Add 1 to the first column (idk if it's right).

  For i = 0 To 25 Step 1 'populate the Combo with 25 items.
      Me.Tamanho.Items.Add(i)
  Next

  UsedMemory = 'I need the ComboValue here As Integer... and I don't know if I need to set up a default value.

  Me.Chart1.Series("Memory").Points.AddXY("Memory", UsedMemory)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Just for readability, it would be best (but not necessary) to first fill the combobox. Then, to retrieve the value, just do it as you would normally do with any other column type.

```
For i = 0 To 25 Step 1 'populate the Combo with 25 items.
    Me.Tamanho.Items.Add(i)
Next

Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", 1) 'the second parameter is the default value the combobox column will have

UsedMemory = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value '0 or any index you need

Me.Chart1.Series("Memory").Points.AddXY("Memory", UsedMemory)
```